# Ubuntu - nodejs - npm install -g > Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, server, digital-ocean

Was having a issue installing a NodeJS `npm` package. On a Digital-Ocean Droplet Ubuntu (14.04) server.

```
 npm install -g PACKAGE-NAME
```

I even tried with `sudo` had the same error.

Error message:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '.....etc'
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Hope this helps someone took me a while to find a way to get this to install.

```
 sudo npm install -g PACKAGE-NAME --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

What the flags do:

**unsafe-perm** - https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm

Default: false if running as root, true otherwise
Type: Boolean
Set to true to suppress the UID/GID switching when running package scripts. If set explicitly to false, then installing as a non-root user will fail.

**allow-root** - https://bower.io/docs/api/#allow-root

--allow-root
Allows running commands as root. Bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions. However, if you still want to run commands with sudo, use --allow-root option.

Comment: This command works fine for Mac as well (which is alike to Linux ).

Comment: @SudirKrishnaaRS yes NPM runs on Mac too.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I didn't want to install npm for all the users. Hence wasn't using `sudo npm ...`. Instead I granted the required permissions to the directory and it worked.

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw ./node_modules/
```