# Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/myname/.config/insight-nodejs/insight-yo.json.3782504431'

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

When I am trying to install a meanjs template with yo generator `sudo yo meanjs`, it gives me this error:

```
 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:236
    throw err
    ^   
 **Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/myname/.config/insight-nodejs/insight-yo.json.1173957578'**
    <br> at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Function.writeFileSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:212:13)
    <br> at Conf.set store [as store] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/conf/index.js:142:19)
    at Conf.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/conf/index.js:64:14)
    at Insight.set optOut [as optOut] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:56:15)
   <br>at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:206:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

- **My global nodejs modules is :**

  'ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules total 52'

```
    drwxr-xr-x 13 root   root  4096 ديسمب  7 18:01 .
    - drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root  4096 أكتوب 21 09:53 ..
    - drwxr-xr-x  4 nobody ayoub 4096 ديسمب  7 17:54 bower
    - drwxr-xr-x  5 nobody ayoub 4096 أكتوب 21 09:59 electron
    - drwxr-xr-x  5 nobody ayoub 4096 ديسمب  6 16:42 express-generator
    - drwxr-xr-x 19 nobody ayoub 4096 ديسمب  7 18:01 generator-meanjs
    - drwxr-xr-x  5 nobody ayoub 4096 نوفمب  8 11:54 grunt
    - drwxr-xr-x  6 nobody ayoub 4096 نوفمب  8 11:52 grunt-cli
    - drwxr-xr-x  4 nobody ayoub 4096 نوفمب  6 21:15 gulp
    - drwxr-xr-x  6 nobody ayoub 4096 نوفمب  8 16:16 gulp-cli
    - drwxr-xr-x  5 nobody ayoub 4096 نوفمب 12 14:10 mern-app-generator
    - drwxr-xr-x  4 nobody ayoub 4096 نوفمب  8 16:43 yarn
    - drwxr-xr-x  4 nobody ayoub 4096 ديسمب  7 17:56 yo
```

And my operation system is: **ubuntu 18.04**

Answer (score 1):

It seems like root user cannot access to this file.
Removing `sudo` before the command walked for me. I mean, just try `yo meanjs`

Answer (score 0):

could you try this :

`sudo npm install -g yo --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

and then run command to create app

`sudo yo meanjs`

If still getting error try this:

`chown -R $USER $HOME/.npm`

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo`

`sudo yo meanjs`

Read more here :

https://github.com/krakenjs/generator-kraken/issues/114#issuecomment-54201366

[Ubuntu - nodejs - npm install -g > Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46439403/ubuntu-nodejs-npm-install-g-error-eacces-permission-denied-mkdir)

Comment: those commands doesn't work with me . can you tell me other way to generate meanjs simple project with node modules §!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command

`sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/myname/.config`